# Apache2 DocumentRoot does not exist

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox

I was using Apache2 with `/var/www/site` and all was working well. We started using proFTPD and we releasised we need to move the sites insie the home directory.

*Note: Home directory was not there was we first installed ubuntu 12.04.*

We want it to be home/username as we have a few local developers who need access to these folders and need FTP. We have tried smbd however we found it did not like our web program Atom.io

**The error**
    Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/russellharrower/www/harrower.xyz/public_html] does not exist

Also I noticed that when i cd to the main system folder (default) I see home, but the only was to access it from within another folder is to `~/home` would this be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should make an user group / groups and give that group / groups write permission to your `/var/www` directories. This way you don't need to mess up with Apache's permissions to `/home` directories.

Comment: but how do I get proFTPD tp pick up that folder?